# Android - EditText text watcher show incorrect values if text start with special char like @ or #

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

I have an edittext. I've added a text watcher to edittext. I listen text changes. İf the word user typing starts with @, I show user suggestions (like when you type @ and twitter show you suggestions)

If text starts with a normal letter everything works fine.

For example:

```
hello @random_user how are you
 @this also works because there is an empty space before '@'
```

This examples works.

However if text starts with special characters Text Watcher shows incorrect values
For example:

```
@hello_user

#someHashtag
```

text watcher return false value. I'm using `onTextChanged` method to track text

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    //Text in edittext is '@user' but I get:
    //start = 0, before = 0 and count = 1;
    //edittext.getSelectionStart() also returns 1 but cursor is at the end of the line.
    //edittext.getText().toString().length() also returns 1 but @user is 5 length.
}
```

How can I solve this?

Edit: `edittext.postdesc.getText().toString()` only returns first char. For example if my text is '@user', getText method only returns @

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround:

```
class TextWatcherExtended(
    private val onTextChanged: (text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) -> Unit
) : TextWatcher {
    private var before = 0
    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
    }

    override fun beforeTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
        this.before = text?.length ?: 0
    }

    override fun onTextChanged(text: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
        onTextChanged.invoke(text, start, this.before, count)
    }
}
```